# $.post not returning data on one server, does on another

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have a simple contact form that uses js to post via php, and read the response to do some simple appending/css to list errors and a successful send. It normally pops up an error on the field if you have left it blank / if it is not a proper address, and when succesful, removes the form and appends a thank you note.

The problem is, while it works perfectly on my own [server](http://www.musterek.net/sandbox/sagalassos_final/), it sends the mail without giving error/success on the [production](http://www.sagalassosnewpublication.com/mailtest.htm)

I'm not using cross-domain requests, and I have tried disabling compression to no avail. Caching is enabled, though it should not matter.

### The javascript

```
    $('.contact-us').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $('.contact-us input, .contact-us textarea').removeAttr('style');
    $('.error').remove();

    var postdata = $('.contact-us').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'contact2.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(returned_data) {

            var j = 0;
            var submit_ok = true;

            $.each(returned_data, function(key, value) {
                if(value != '') {
                    $('.contact-us .' + key).attr('style', 'border-color: #e67632; -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;');
                    $('.contact-us .' + key).focus();
                    $('.contact-us').append('<div class="error"> ' + value + '</div>');
                    $('.error').css('top', (j*52) + 'px');
                    $('.error').fadeIn('slow');
                    submit_ok = false;
                    return false;
                }
                j++;
            });

            if(submit_ok) {
                $('.contact-us').append('<p style="display: none;">Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you very soon.</p>');
                $('.contact-us input, .contact-us textarea, .contact-us button').remove();
                $('.contact-us p').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### The php

```
<?php
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*    [[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

$emailTo = 'myemail@gmail.com';

$clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
$clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

$errors_array = array('name' => '', 'email' => '', 'subject' => '', 'message' => '');

if($clientName == '') {
    $errors_array['name'] = 'Please enter your name!';
}
if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
    $errors_array['email'] = 'Insert a valid email address!';
}
if($subject == '') {
    $errors_array['subject'] = 'Please enter the subject!';
}
if($message == '') {
    $errors_array['message'] = 'Please enter your message!';
}

if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '' && $subject != '') {
    // Send email
$headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

echo json_encode($errors_array);

}

?>
```

Comment: Mime type set correctly on other server?

Comment: If the action is happening on the server but you're not seeing the response come through the browser, very likely this is in fact a cross domain issue. Cross domain can happen if the protocols mismatch (https vs http). I'd recommend using jsonp, which is designed to get around cross domain issues.

Comment: Your mailing script is problematic and I would not recommend to use it. You don't validate the input of e.g. `clientName` to not contain e.g. `\r\n` so other headers can be injected, e.g. `Content-Type`, `MIME-Version`, `BCC`, `CC` and depending on how your mail server is configured this would be really problematic. Generally I would recommend to use active developed library to create and send mails.

Comment: Bucky24, how would I modify this to work with jsonp?

t.niese, that is helpful, as I have no knowledge of php and took this blob from someone else in the first place. Do you have any suggestions for a simple lib?

Comment: are these what you mean?
[phpformgenerator](http://phpformgen.sourceforge.net/)
[zebraforms](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-form/) 
[phorm fork](https://github.com/tf198/phorms)

Comment: @whatsnewsisyphus the last news of phpformgenerator is from 2007. I don't do much php dev anymore, but i would go with the Zend Framework, because of its strong relation to php (both are _supervise_ by Zend Technology).

Comment: thank you @t.niese I was looking into zebra because it is well commented for beginners, and very frequently updated, but will check zend as well.

Comment: @whatsnewsisyphus you can for sure mix libraries most modern libraries use the same class naming and folder structure conversation. I don't know if zebra has a lib for mail sending. But the one of Zend is pretty easy, you should invest the time to understand, this is better then becoming a spam sender ;)

Comment: Call me an idiot but I am no php programmer, so reading about Zend for an hour taught me basically nothing, is there a tutorial somewhere?